# clear and resize vector - c++

Tags: c++, vector, resize

I'm trying to make a vector, then enter a while cycle, use that vector, then, resize the vector at the end of each cycle. So I decided to make `my_vector.clear()` at the end of the cycle and a `my_vector.resize(newSize)` at the beginning of it. Here's a sample code:

```
typedef struct my_type{
    int numNextDom;
    bool knockedDown;
} my_type;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    int i, testCase, totalDom, numLines, num_dom=0, num_next_dom=0, aux_map_int = 0, linesScanned = 0;
    bool firstTime=true;

    std::cin>>testCase;
    std::vector<my_type> my_vector;

    while(aux_map_int < testCase){

        std::cin>>totalSize>>numLines;

        my_vector.resize(totalSize);

        while (linesScanned < numLines) {
            std::cin>>num_dom>>num_next_dom;

            if(firstTime){
                my_vector[0].numNextDom = totalSize;
                my_vector[0].knockedDown = true;
                firstTime=false;
            }
            my_vector[num_dom].numNextDom = num_next_dom;
            my_vector[num_dom].knockedDown = false;

            linesScanned++;
        }

        std::cout << giveResult(my_vector) << std::endl;
        aux_map_int++;
        my_vector.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So you see, after I make `my_vector.clean()` the vector becomes os size 1, but then, when the loop is re-done, `my_vector` stays of size 1 and doesn't do the `my_vector.resize(totalSize)`.
Am I missing anything?

Comment: How are you determining the size?

Comment: " the vector becomes os size 1" <- how are you getting this size?  The `size()` of the vector should be 0 after a clear; `capacity()` should not change.  `sizeof` will report something totally different...is that what you're using?

Comment: @sftrabbit doesn't `resize` does that?
@CrazyEddie yes, that's what I was using..

Comment: @FriedRike You're doing `sizeof(my_vector)`?

Comment: @sftrabbit actually no, my mistake. I has a function to print `my_vector`and it only printed one element. So I assumed it only had size of 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran your code and the vector is correctly resized.

I think your problem is that you are not resetting `linesScanned` after the first test, so if `totalSize` is smaller on the second iteration of the loop than it was on the first one, you will not enter the body of the second loop at all. Even if it is bigger the second time, you will not get the behaviour you expect.

You can fix this issue by adding `linesScanned = 0;` as the first statement of the outer loop, i.e. just after `while(aux_map_int < testCase){`

Also, I suggest you use for loops, as they are cleaner and would help you avoid such mistakes in the future.

Here is the program that I tested:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int totalSize = 0;

typedef struct my_type{
    int numNextDom;
    bool knockedDown;
} my_type;

int giveResult(std::vector<my_type>);

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    int i, testCase, totalDom, numLines, num_dom=0, num_next_dom=0, aux_map_int = 0, linesScanned = 0;
    bool firstTime=true;

    std::cin>>testCase;
    std::vector<my_type> my_vector;

    while(aux_map_int < testCase){

        std::cin>>totalSize>>numLines;

        my_vector.resize(totalSize);
        std::cout << "my_vector.size(): " << my_vector.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "linesScanned: " << linesScanned << std::endl;
        std::cout << "numLines: " << numLines << std::endl;

        while (linesScanned < numLines) {
            std::cin>>num_dom>>num_next_dom;

            if(firstTime){
                my_vector[0].numNextDom = totalSize;
                my_vector[0].knockedDown = true;
                firstTime=false;
            }
            my_vector[num_dom].numNextDom = num_next_dom;
            my_vector[num_dom].knockedDown = false;

            linesScanned++;
        }

        std::cout << giveResult(my_vector) << std::endl;
        aux_map_int++;
        my_vector.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}

int giveResult(std::vector<my_type>) {
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the interaction session from my console:

```
2
2 2
my_vector.size(): 2
linesScanned: 0
numLines: 2
5 5
6 6
0
3 2
my_vector.size(): 3
linesScanned: 2
numLines: 2
```

Here you can see that linesScanned is not reset and is going to cause a problem.

Here is correct (with respect to this problem) version of your main function:

```
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    int i, testCase, totalDom, numLines, num_dom=0, num_next_dom=0, aux_map_int = 0, linesScanned = 0;
    bool firstTime=true;

    std::cin>>testCase;
    std::vector<my_type> my_vector;

    while(aux_map_int < testCase){
        linesScanned = 0;
        std::cin>>totalSize>>numLines;

        my_vector.resize(totalSize);

        while (linesScanned < numLines) {
            std::cin>>num_dom>>num_next_dom;

            if(firstTime){
                my_vector[0].numNextDom = totalSize;
                my_vector[0].knockedDown = true;
                firstTime=false;
            }
            my_vector[num_dom].numNextDom = num_next_dom;
            my_vector[num_dom].knockedDown = false;

            linesScanned++;
        }

        std::cout << giveResult(my_vector) << std::endl;
        aux_map_int++;
        my_vector.clear();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I hope that clears it up.

-Stan